# C++ NeuralNetwork class has no member topology

Tags: c++, neural-network

I'm having some trouble following a guide at:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-neural-network-implementation-in-c-from-scratch/
I have installed the eigen library with vcpkg and it seems to be working because it gives no error.

Code:

```
#pragma once
// NeuralNetwork.hpp 
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Eigen> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <vector> 

// use typedefs for future ease for changing data types like : float to double 
typedef float Scalar;
typedef Eigen::MatrixXf Matrix;
typedef Eigen::RowVectorXf RowVector;
typedef Eigen::VectorXf ColVector;

// neural network implementation class! 
class NeuralNetwork {
public:
    // constructor 
    NeuralNetwork(std::vector<unsigned int> topology, Scalar learningRate = Scalar(0.005));

    // function for forward propagation of data 
    void propagateForward(RowVector& input);

    // function for backward propagation of errors made by neurons 
    void propagateBackward(RowVector& output);

    // function to calculate errors made by neurons in each layer 
    void calcErrors(RowVector& output);

    // function to update the weights of connections 
    void updateWeights();

    // function to train the neural network give an array of data points 
    void train(std::vector<RowVector*> data);

    // storage objects for working of neural network 
    /*
          use pointers when using std::vector<Class> as std::vector<Class> calls destructor of
          Class as soon as it is pushed back! when we use pointers it can't do that, besides
          it also makes our neural network class less heavy!! It would be nice if you can use
          smart pointers instead of usual ones like this
        */
    std::vector<RowVector*> neuronLayers; // stores the different layers of out network 
    std::vector<RowVector*> cacheLayers; // stores the unactivated (activation fn not yet applied) values of layers 
    std::vector<RowVector*> deltas; // stores the error contribution of each neurons 
    std::vector<Matrix*> weights; // the connection weights itself 
    Scalar learningRate;
};



// constructor of neural network class 
NeuralNetwork::NeuralNetwork(std::vector<unsigned int> topology, Scalar learningRate)
{
    this->topology = topology; //<- ERROR HERE
    this->learningRate = learningRate;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < topology.size(); i++) {
        // initialze neuron layers 
        if (i == topology.size() - 1)
            neuronLayers.push_back(new RowVector(topology[i]));
        else
            neuronLayers.push_back(new RowVector(topology[i] + 1));

        // initialize cache and delta vectors 
        cacheLayers.push_back(new RowVector(neuronLayers.size()));
        deltas.push_back(new RowVector(neuronLayers.size()));

        // vector.back() gives the handle to recently added element 
        // coeffRef gives the reference of value at that place  
        // (using this as we are using pointers here) 
        if (i != topology.size() - 1) {
            neuronLayers.back()->coeffRef(topology[i]) = 1.0;
            cacheLayers.back()->coeffRef(topology[i]) = 1.0;
        }

        // initialze weights matrix 
        if (i > 0) {
            if (i != topology.size() - 1) {
                weights.push_back(new Matrix(topology[i - 1] + 1, topology[i] + 1));
                weights.back()->setRandom();
                weights.back()->col(topology[i]).setZero();
                weights.back()->coeffRef(topology[i - 1], topology[i]) = 1.0;
            }
            else {
                weights.push_back(new Matrix(topology[i - 1] + 1, topology[i]));
                weights.back()->setRandom();
            }
        }
    }
};



// constructor of neural network class 
NeuralNetwork::NeuralNetwork(std::vector<unsigned int> topology,Scalar learningRate)
{
    this->topology = topology;
    this->learningRate = learningRate;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < topology.size(); i++) {
        // initialze neuron layers 
        if (i == topology.size() - 1)
            neuronLayers.push_back(new RowVector(topology[i]));
        else
            neuronLayers.push_back(new RowVector(topology[i] + 1));

        // initialize cache and delta vectors 
        cacheLayers.push_back(new RowVector(neuronLayers.size()));
        deltas.push_back(new RowVector(neuronLayers.size()));

        // vector.back() gives the handle to recently added element 
        // coeffRef gives the reference of value at that place  
        // (using this as we are using pointers here) 
        if (i != topology.size() - 1) {
            neuronLayers.back()->coeffRef(topology[i]) = 1.0;
            cacheLayers.back()->coeffRef(topology[i]) = 1.0;
        }

        // initialze weights matrix 
        if (i > 0) {
            if (i != topology.size() - 1) {
                weights.push_back(new Matrix(topology[i - 1] + 1, topology[i] + 1));
                weights.back()->setRandom();
                weights.back()->col(topology[i]).setZero();
                weights.back()->coeffRef(topology[i - 1], topology[i]) = 1.0;
            }
            else {
                weights.push_back(new Matrix(topology[i - 1] + 1, topology[i]));
                weights.back()->setRandom();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The error I get is:

```
class NeuralNetwork has no member "topology"
```

Im at loss here, I don't understand why it gives me this error when "topology" is actually in the constructor.

Comment: The code is in error, it's missing the definition for std::vector<uint> topology;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what it says on the tin, the list of members in the class declaration:

```cpp
class NeuralNetwork {
//...
    std::vector<RowVector*> neuronLayers; // stores the different layers of out network 
    std::vector<RowVector*> cacheLayers; // stores the unactivated (activation fn not yet applied) values of layers 
    std::vector<RowVector*> deltas; // stores the error contribution of each neurons 
    std::vector<Matrix*> weights; // the connection weights itself 
    Scalar learningRate;
};
```

Contains no member named exactly `topology`. The only members are:

- `neuronLayers`
- `cacheLayers`
- `deltas`
- `weights`
- `learningRate`

Comment: Thank you! Makes so much sense. Don't know why the guide author wouldn't  have a topology member himself.

Comment: @Gustav If this answer satisfied your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark in the upper left.